# Error connecting to MSSQL on PHP UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, odbc

I have such a problem, I can’t connect to the Mssql database, I installed the sqlsrv driver.
installed odbc
phpinfo sees everything.

### But still with such a request

```
<?php


$server = ""************";
$database = ""************";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "Uid" => ""************",
    "PWD" => "************",
);


$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionOptions);

if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    echo "ok!";
    
}

// Закрытие соединения
sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

---

Gives this error

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) )
```

Followed the link installed the odbc driver as needed, prescribed files for it
I write this request in the console

```
 isql sudo odbcinst -q -d -n "myodbc"
```

And I get an answer

```
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Can you help, I've been working for 2 days and I can't change what's wrong.

Here are the obdc files and responses to queries

```
    /etc/odbc.ini
[my_mysql_dsn]
Driver      = myodbc
Server      = *********
Port        = 3306
Database    = *********
User        = *********
Password    = *********

/etc/odbcinst.ini
[myodbc]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2.0.0
Setup       = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2.0.0
FileUsage   = 1


dpkg -l | grep odbc


ii  libodbc2:amd64                        2.3.9-5                                      amd64        ODBC Driver Manager library for Unix
ii  libodbccr2:amd64                      2.3.9-5                                      amd64        ODBC Cursor library for Unix
ii  libodbcinst2:amd64                    2.3.9-5                                      amd64        Support library for accessing ODBC configuration files
ii  odbcinst                              2.3.9-5                                      amd64        Helper program for accessing ODBC configuration files
ii  php-odbc                              2:8.1+92ubuntu1                              all          ODBC module for PHP [default]
ii  php8.1-odbc                           8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13                            amd64        ODBC module for PHP
ii  unixodbc                              2.3.9-5                                      amd64        Basic ODBC tools
ii  unixodbc-common                       2.3.9-5                                      all          Common ODBC configuration files
ii  unixodbc-dev:amd64                    2.3.9-5                                      amd64        ODBC libraries for Unix (development files)
```

phpinfo :
[image]

Comment: mySQL !== msSQL